# Protege and java

Tags: protege

How to open, read and manipulate the contents of .owl file in java?

Comment: A [3-second Google search](http://www.google.com/search?&q=java+protege+owl) turned up [the Protégé-OWL API](http://protege.stanford.edu/plugins/owl/api/). Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Another API for manipulating RDF and OWL etc is Jena.